# How to edit git config to Run Git and included Unix tools from the Windows Command Prompt

Tags: git

When installing git for windows, a user is asked to select from following 3 options:

1. (default) Use Git Bash Only
2. Run Git from Windows Command Line
3. Run Git and included Unix tools from the windows command prompt

I installed with option 1 selected, but now want to change to option 3. How can I do this?

EDIT:
want to add some useful links to help with git installation:
http://mechanicalrevolution.com/blog/git_installation.html
http://www.diplo.co.uk/blog/2011/6/2/installing-git-on-windows.aspx
http://gitscc.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` from the path and replace it with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`

This option just selects what goes onto the path. If you just add the Git\cmd\ directory to the path then that provides a git.cmd and a gitk.cmd which let you work properly from the Windows command prompt.

To edit the PATH environment variable, you need to use the Advanced System Settings dialog from the control panel system settings page and click the Environment Variables button. Unfortunately the edit window is really small - its usually helpful to copy the PATH value into notepad to edit then paste it back in after.

Alternatively, you could uninstall and reinstall Git with the correct setting selected.

Comment: its actually the opposite.
option 1 is nothing gets added to path
option 2 is C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd is added to path
option 3 is C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin is added to path
as far as I can tell